# SQL Pivot select multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

This is the table I have:

[image: Tasble for pivot looks like this]

I want to create pivot like this:
[image]

I've wrote some query, but I get only names diagonally:

```
(
select 
[1] as Client0, 
[2] as Client1, 
[3] as Client2, 
[4] as Client3,
[5] as Client4
from 
(
select 
    rc.DateCreated, 
    gd.Name,
    DENSE_RANK() over (order by gd.ID_TableGD) as colnum
from TableGD gd
inner join TableRC rc ON gd.ID_TableGD = rc.ID_TableRC
WHERE gd.ID_TableGD IN (962,1029,1024) 
AND gd.Active = 1
) as t
pivot
(
MAX(Name)
for colnum in 
(
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5]

)
) as pvt)
```

So, I want to be able for particular client to get clientName (ClientA) and CreatedDate in same column.

This is my first pivot, and I am not sure if I need to put Max(Name)?

And I get table like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max in time of selection like below:

```
select 
max([1]) as Client0, 
max([2]) as Client1, 
max([3]) as Client2, 
max([4]) as Client3,
max([5]) as Client4
from 
(
select 
    rc.DateCreated, 
    gd.Name,
    DENSE_RANK() over (order by gd.ID_TableGD) as colnum
from TableGD gd
inner join TableRC rc ON gd.ID_TableGD = rc.ID_TableRC
WHERE gd.ID_TableGD IN (962,1029,1024) 
AND gd.Active = 1
) as t
pivot
(
MAX(Name)
for colnum in 
(
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5]

)
) as pvt
```

Comment: now I have only one row which is great, but I still need datecreated row, just below the name row

Comment: do the same with union all - it will give you desired result

Comment: It gives me an error for casting 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' Where I need to cast? columns in pivot? @fa06

Answer (score 2):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` with `Value` to do that.

first, you need to do `unpivot` to let your `DateCreated` and `Name` in one column, which is from your expected result.

let result look like this.

```
SELECT 
  v.*
FROM T t1 CROSS APPLY(
    VALUES 
    (Name,colnum,1),
    (CAST(DateCreated AS VARCHAR(50)),colnum,2)
) v (val,colnum,grp)
```

**Results**:

```
|        val | colnum | grp |
|------------|--------|-----|
|    ClientA |      1 |   1 |
| 2018-08-21 |      1 |   2 |
|    ClientB |      2 |   1 |
| 2018-08-22 |      2 |   2 |
|    ClientC |      3 |   1 |
| 2018-08-23 |      3 |   2 |
```

---

Next Step you can try to use `Pivot` let vertical data to horizontal.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Name VARCHAR(50),
   DateCreated DATE,
   colnum INT
);
INSERT INTO T VALUES('ClientA','2018-08-21',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES('ClientB','2018-08-22',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES('ClientC','2018-08-23',3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.colnum = 1 THEN v.val end) client0,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.colnum = 2 THEN v.val end) client1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.colnum = 3 THEN v.val end) client2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.colnum = 4 THEN v.val end) client3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.colnum = 5 THEN v.val end) client4
FROM T t1 CROSS APPLY(
    VALUES 
    (Name,colnum,1),
    (CAST(DateCreated AS VARCHAR(50)),colnum,2)
) v (val,colnum,grp)
group by grp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef96e/12/0)**:

```
|    client0 |    client1 |    client2 | client3 | client4 |
|------------|------------|------------|---------|---------|
|    ClientA |    ClientB |    ClientC |  (null) |  (null) |
| 2018-08-21 | 2018-08-22 | 2018-08-23 |  (null) |  (null) |
```

[CROSS APPLY ... Value](https://sqlstudies.com/2013/05/20/the-many-uses-of-cross-apply/)

**NOTE**

If you want to show your original datetime format.

You could use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to translate your expect datetime format.

This sample is for `FORMAT` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12ae9e/3

Although `format` is simpler to use than `Convert`, it is poor performance when it comes to multiple data.

Comment: can you please give me an example with my query? thanks

Comment: @Stefan0309 Ok wait a second I add some explanation.

Comment: @Stefan0309 I add some explanation for you

Comment: excellent. It works! Only when it cast date to nvarchar, I get different format like: Aug 21 2018  4:41PM Can I keep sql dateformat in nvarchar like: 2018-08-21 16:41:00 ?

Comment: You can use `CONVERT `or `FORMAT` to translate your expect datetime format. this sample is for  `FORMAT`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12ae9e/3